# How to add an Action in Jenkins Build page

Tags: jenkins-plugins

How can I add information on the main section of a build page? Which class do I need to implement?

(I've already managed to get my plugin working as a post-build step, on the project level and the build page left menu)

[image: Jenkins build page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `summary.jelly` was missing from the `PluginBuildAction` resource:

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout"
         xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form" xmlns:i="jelly:fmt">
    <t:summary icon="orange-square.png">
        Surprise! <br/>
    </t:summary>
</j:jelly>
```